# Using "ifelse" with negative values - R

Tags: r, if-statement, sentiment-analysis, vader

I did a sentiment analysis using VADER and now want to classify the values with negative, positive and neutral.

Positive when compound score is > 0.05

Negative when its < - 0.05
neutral when in between -0.05 and 0.05

```
df_polarity$VADER_Sent = ifelse(df_polarity$VADER_Sent > 0.05, "pos", 
                            ifelse (df_polarity$VADER_Sent < -0.05, "neg", 
                                    ifelse (between(df_polarity$VADER_Sent, -0.05, 0.05) , "neu", "NA")
                            ) 
)
```

When running this code, even values with - 0.4XXX will be classified as neutral and not as negative.

For some reason this won't work. There is anything I am missing... but I can figure out what it is...

I couldn't find any helpful tipps by googling it.

I hope someone of you can help me with this one!

Output from str(df_polarity):

> $ VADER_Sent   : chr  "0.0" "-0.4939" "0.7717" "0.7096"

After further looking into my data, it seems that the "-" sign is not recognized in the context of a negative number.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me! Really appreciated it!!!

Comment: Can you post some data? Where is `between` from?

Comment: The last `ifelse` seems not needed, because the NA case will never happen

Comment: The `between` function is the basic R one, replacing `x >= left & x <= right`.

Comment: There is no `between` function in base R.

Comment: @Basti  even if I remove the last `ifelse` I still get the faulty results. Still all values below 0.05 will be classified as "neu" even if they should be "neg"

Comment: @user2974951Sorry, my mistake! its from "dplyr". I had the code with `x >= left & x <= right` at first -> Same results.

Comment: Then please show `str(df_polarity)` your data may be not correctly formatted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the `VADER_Sent` column is character. The comparisons `<` and `>` are checking alphabetically instead of numerically.

Example:

```
> -0.4939 < -0.05
[1] TRUE

> "-0.4939" < "-0.05"
[1] FALSE
```

Try using `as.numeric(df_polarity$VADER_Sent)` in your `ifelse()` statements to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be sure without reproducible code, but you should be able to just give the 'neutral' category as the second option in the second `ifelse()` call.

```
df_polarity$VADER_Sent = ifelse(df_polarity$VADER_Sent > 0.05, "pos", 
                            ifelse(df_polarity$VADER_Sent < -0.05, "neg", "neutral"
                         )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df %>%
  mutate(X = if_else(VADER_sent < -0.5, "neg", 
                    if_else(VADER_sent <= 0.5 & VADER_sent >= -0.5, "neutral", "pos"))
  )
  VADER_sent       X
1       0.51     pos
2       0.10 neutral
3       2.00     pos
4      -0.60     neg
5       0.30 neutral
6      -1.20     neg
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  VADER_sent = c(0.51, 0.1, 2,-0.6, 0.3, -1.2)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for you anwser! I just tried it and it sadly didn't work with my data... It seems to be some problem with the values in the "VADER_Sent" column...

Comment: I just checked the Vader_Sent column with sapply( X , mode). It says "character" for that column, maybe the problem is here?